# Shopify: Edit a mega-menu to open/close on click, not on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, megamenu

I'm trying to edit my Shopify's theme. I want to open/close the mega-menu with a click instead of on hover. I taught myself to code HTML & CSS and I've just started to explore javascript / JQuery. I'm still learning. Anyway, I'm hoping this will be an easy fix.

I've made a little bit of progress by changing the 'mouseenter' 'mouseleave' to 'click' in the javascript. By doing that, I could open the menu with a click and it stayed open. Great. But I couldn't close it on click and it was stuck open. I think I might need to use the .toggle() method somewhere but I'm at a loss where to even start. Help!

HTML:

```
   <div id="main-nav">
    <div class="navigation navigation--main" role="navigation" aria-label="Primary navigation">
      <div class="navigation__tier-1-container">
        <ul class="navigation__tier-1">
         
<li class="navigation__item navigation__item--with-children">
              <a href="#" class="navigation__link" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="NavigationTier2-1">Browse</a>
      
                <a class="navigation__children-toggle" href="#"></a>
              
<div id="NavigationTier2-1" class="navigation__tier-2-container navigation__child-tier">
                  <ul class="navigation__tier-2 navigation__columns navigation__columns--count-2">
                    
                    <li class="navigation__item navigation__column">
                      <a href="/collections/new-arrivals" class="navigation__link">New Arrivals</a>
```

CSS:

```
.navigation {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: {{ font_size_nav_int }}px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.navigation ul,
.navigation li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navigation li {
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navigation--left {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  visibility: hidden;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navigation--left {
    display: block;
  }
}

.navigation--left .navigation__tier-1-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: calc(-18px - 0.75em);
  left: -18px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation__item {
  display: block;
}

.navigation__link {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 18px;
}

.navigation__link[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: {{ font_col_link_hover }};
}

.navigation .navigation__item--with-children {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navigation .navigation__item--with-children > .navigation__link {
  max-width: calc(100% - 60px);
}

.navigation .navigation__item--with-children .navigation__tier-2-container,
.navigation .navigation__item--with-children .navigation__tier-3-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation .navigation__children-toggle {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: inherit;
}

.navigation .navigation__children-toggle:hover {
  color: inherit;
}

.navigation .navigation__children-toggle .feather {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

.navigation .navigation__tier-1 > .navigation__item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navigation .navigation__tier-2-container,
.navigation .navigation__tier-3-container {
  display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
     cc.sections.push({
    name: 'store-availability',
    section: theme.StoreAvailability
  });
  theme.Navigation = {
    init: function init(options) {
      if (options.nav.length == 0) {
        return;
      }
      
      var $nav = options.nav,
          navHoverDelay = 250,
          $navLastOpenDropdown = $(),
          navOpenTimeoutId = -1; // hover events

      $nav.on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.navigation__tier-1 > .navigation__item--with-children', function (evt) {
        var $dropdownContainer = $(this); // delay on hover-out

        if (evt.type == 'mouseenter') {
          clearTimeout(navOpenTimeoutId);
          clearTimeout($dropdownContainer.data('navCloseTimeoutId'));
          var $openSiblings = $dropdownContainer.siblings('.navigation__item--show-children'); // close all menus but last opened

          $openSiblings.not($navLastOpenDropdown).removeClass('navigation__item--show-children');
          $navLastOpenDropdown = $dropdownContainer; // show after a delay, based on first-open or not

          var timeoutDelay = $openSiblings.length == 0 ? 0 : navHoverDelay; // open it

          var newNavOpenTimeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
            $dropdownContainer.addClass('navigation__item--show-children').siblings('.navigation__item--show-children').removeClass('navigation__item--show-children');
          }, timeoutDelay);
          navOpenTimeoutId = newNavOpenTimeoutId;
          $dropdownContainer.data('navOpenTimeoutId', newNavOpenTimeoutId);
        } else {
          // cancel opening, close after delay, and clear transforms
          clearTimeout($dropdownContainer.data('navOpenTimeoutId'));
          $dropdownContainer.data('navCloseTimeoutId', setTimeout(function () {
            $dropdownContainer.removeClass('navigation__item--show-children');
          }, navHoverDelay));
        } // a11y


        $dropdownContainer.children('[aria-expanded]').attr('aria-expanded', evt.type == 'mouseenter');
      }); // touch events on desktop

      var touchHandler = function touchHandler(evt) {
        if ($(window).width() > 767) {
          if (evt.type == 'touchstart') {
            $(this).data('touchstartedAt', evt.timeStamp);
          } else if (evt.type == 'touchend') {
            // down & up in under a second - presume tap
            if (evt.timeStamp - $(this).data('touchstartedAt') < 1000) {
              $(this).data('touchOpenTriggeredAt', evt.timeStamp);

              if ($(this).parent().hasClass('navigation__item--show-children')) {
                // trigger close
                $(this).parent().trigger('mouseleave');
              } else {
                // trigger close on any open items
                $('.navigation:first .navigation__item--show-children').trigger('mouseleave'); // trigger open

                $(this).parent().trigger('mouseenter');
              } // prevent fake click


              return false;
            }
          } else if (evt.type == 'click') {
            // if touch open was triggered very recently, prevent click event
            if ($(this).data('touchOpenTriggeredAt') && evt.timeStamp - $(this).data('touchOpenTriggeredAt') < 1000) {
              return false;
            }
          }
        }
      };

      $nav.on('touchstart touchend click', '.navigation__tier-1 > .navigation__item--with-children > .navigation__link', touchHandler); // hit return on dropdown toggle

      var keydownHandler = function keydownHandler(evt) {
        if (evt.which == 13) {
          var $parent = $(this).parent();
          $parent.trigger($parent.hasClass('navigation__item--show-children') ? 'mouseleave' : 'mouseenter');
          return false;
        }
      };

      $nav.on('keydown', '.navigation__tier-1 > .navigation__item--with-children > .navigation__children-toggle', keydownHandler); // proxy for desktop nav interaction events

      if (options.proxyTier1Nav) {
        $(options.proxyTier1Nav).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.navigation__tier-1 > .navigation__item--with-children', function (evt) {
          $($('.navigation__tier-1 > .navigation__item', $nav)[$(this).index()]).trigger(evt.type);
        }).on('touchstart touchend click', '.navigation__tier-1 > .navigation__item--with-children > .navigation__link', function (evt) {
          var response = touchHandler.bind($($('.navigation__tier-1 > .navigation__item', $nav)[$(this).parent().index()]).children('.navigation__link')[0])(evt);

          if (response === false) {
            return false;
          }
        }).on('keydown', '.navigation__tier-1 > .navigation__item--with-children > .navigation__children-toggle', function (evt) {
          if (evt.which == 13) {
            keydownHandler.bind($($('.navigation__tier-1 > .navigation__item', $nav)[$(this).parent().index()]).children('.navigation__children-toggle')[0])(evt);
            return false;
          }
        });
      } // mobile expansion


      $nav.on('click', '.navigation__children-toggle', function () {
        if ($(this).parent().toggleClass('navigation__item--mobile-open').hasClass('navigation__item--mobile-open')) {
          $(this).siblings('.navigation__child-tier').stop().slideDown(300, function () {
            $(this).parent().addClass('navigation__item--mobile-open-finished');
            $(this).removeAttr('style');
          });
        } else {
          $(this).siblings('.navigation__child-tier').stop().slideUp(300, function () {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('navigation__item--mobile-open-finished');
            $(this).removeAttr('style');
          });
        }

        return false;
      });
    },
    destroy: function destroy($nav, $proxyTier1Nav) {
      $nav.add($proxyTier1Nav).off('click mouseenter mouseleave touchstart touchend keydown');
    }
  };
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Handle the click to open and close the dropdown by the following

```
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
});
```

and then listening to the clicks outside of the dropdown to close it like this :

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    if (!$('li.navigation__item').is(e.target) 
        && $('li.navigation__item').has(e.target).length === 0 
        && $('.open').has(e.target).length === 0
    ) {
        $('li.navigation__item').removeClass('open');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure I follow. And, it's still unclear to me how to integrate this suggestion into my code. I appreciate the help.